# how to use a variable inside a nginx "if" regular expression

Tags: regex, nginx

I have a caching system I need to bypass if the user's name (in a cookie) is found in the $request_uri. I'm trying to do something like this, but can't get the variable to interpolate into the regex. Any suggestions pretty please?

I can set the $me variable just fine from the cookie; I just can't get it to interpolate into the regex.

```
set $chk == "need"; 
set $me "kevin"; 
if ($uri ~ $me) { set $chk ""; } 
if ($chk == "need") { rewrite ^ /testing }
```

I've always tried things like this:

```
if ($uri ~ "by-{$me}") { set $chk ""; }
```

Thanks!
-Kevin

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's not exactly what I asked, but I think it'll work for my purposes.  I'm still curious how to interpolate a variable inside a nginx PCRE regex if anyone else knows!

```
set $chk == "need"; 
set $me "kevin"; 
if ($uri ~ /by-([^-]+)/) { set $by $1; }
if ($by = $me) {set $chk "";}
```

Comment: You have a syntax error on the first line, I think. The double equals operator shouldn't be there. I thought that was *my* problem for a second, but putting them into a config file won't pass any pre-launch checks.

Answer (score -2):

It's possible to incorporate a variable within a regex expression by just putting $ in front of the variable ... no need to do ${}

so I suppose in your case

```
if ($uri ~ "by-$me") { set $chk ""; }
```

the regular expression will then be equal to by-kevin

I've had it work like this for a more complex regex rule

where I wanted orgin to match a list of possible domain names

```
set $domainWhitelist "yahoo\.com|google\.com|foo\.com";
if ($http_origin ~* "https?://([\w-]*\.)*($domainWhitelist)(:\d+)?") {
...
}
```

Comment: doesn't work for me. Logs show variable name instead: ```2018/07/14 19:03:59 [notice] 6#0: *1 "https?://([\w-]*\.)*($domainWhitelist)(:\d+)?" does not match ```...

Comment: There is an open issue on Github since 2013 saying this does not exist in nginx. I am curious if/how you got this to work.
https://github.com/openresty/replace-filter-nginx-module/issues/5